# simple python stage game issue (with no graphyx)

Tags: python

**my py game: **

```
import sys
import emoji
print("welcom my friend i am deadhead yes that dead head, deadhead the almighty,you are going to chalenge me in a battle ")
print("know that its all random and by luck so if you defeated me you are not more powerfull than me you're just lucky...")
print("rules are simple you gotta choose one of these buttons (q,w,e,r), my hp is (1000)")
input("ok if you are ready you can beging the battle by pressing inter button...")
button = ["q","w","e","r"]
random.choice(button)
damage1 = [100,200,300,1000]
x=random.choice(damage1)
y=input("choose your button(q,w,e,r): ")
if y in button:
   print (x)
if x == 1000:
   print("you lucky bitch you one shotted me!!!")
   input("till the next time lucky ass nigga")
   sys.exit()

elif():
   damage2 = [100,200,300,1000]
   x2=random.choice(damage2)
   print(x2)
   input("ok lets go for another round shall we?")
   damage3 = [100,200,300,1000]
   x3=random.choice(damage)
   print(x3)
   input("ouch!,good another one ")
   damage4 = [100,200,300,1000]
   x4=random.choice(damage4)
   print(x4)
if x+x2+x3+x4 > 1000:
   print("oh ma lord i have been defeated ")
   input("youknow that i never die yeah? ok till the next time :thumbsup: ")
   
   sys.exit()
else:
   print("huh you have been defeated :D")
   input("GG man till the next time :thumbsup: ")
```

ok here you see my codes but the problem is why it cannot find my x2 ,x3 and x4 names , and i also gotta tell that i tried putting my variables above my "elif"  but i got another syntax error and here is the exact error that i get :

- if x+x2+x3+x4 > 1000:
  NameError: name 'x2' is not defined*

Comment: Use `else:` instead of `elif():`.

Comment: `elif()` is wrong (you have to remove the brackets). and you only define the variables, if you reach the elif, but not if your code runs into the second `if`

Comment: aha oh for the tips guys

Comment: *thank you (forgot to say it)